# List of lists equivalent for numpy 2D indexing [:,0]

Tags: python

I need to access the first element of each list within a list. Usually I do this via numpy arrays by indexing:

```
import numpy as np
nparr=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
first_elements = nparr[:,0]
```

b/c:

```
print(nparr[0,:])
[1 2 3]
print(nparr[:,0])
[1 4 7]
```

Unfortunately I have to tackle non-rectangular dynamic arrays now so numpy won't work.

But Pythons standard lists behave strangely (at least for me):

```
pylist=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(pylist[0][:])
[1, 2, 3]
print(pylist[:][0])
[1, 2, 3]
```

I guess either lists doesn't support this (which would lead to a second question: What to use instead) or I got the syntax wrong?

Comment: your desire output?

Comment: `print([item[0] for item in pylist])` will yield you the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Ben and mrin9san. So I guess the answer is: No, you can't do it purely by indicies... 
List comprehension for the win is it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options. Here's one.

```
pylist=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(pylist[0])                  # [1, 2, 3]
print([row[0] for row in pylist]) # [1, 4, 7]
```

Alternatively, if you want to transpose `pylist` (make its rows into columns), you could do the following.

```
pylist_transpose = [*zip(*pylist)]
print(pylist_transpose[0])        # [1, 4, 7]
```

`pylist_transpose` will always be a rectangular array with a number of rows equal to the length of the shortest row in `pylist`.

Comment: Clever idea to transpose! Hopefully I'll remember when applicable. Thanks!